# Data type modifier and shift operator

Tags: c

```
int main(void)  
{  

   unsigned i = -23; // line 1
   short a, b = 0x1;

   printf("sizeof(short) = %i\n", (int)sizeof(short)); // line 2

   a = b << 31; // line 3
   printf("i = %i", i); // line 4
   printf("i = %u", i); // line 5

   return 0;
}
```

Why line 1 isn't giving any error when type modifier unsigned is specified ?

Line 2 prints `sizeof(short)` in my system as 2 bytes. a & b are short integers hence 2 bytes or 16 bits long . But line 3 doesn't throws any error. How left shifting by 31 bit is possible when word length is 16 bit only ??

Are there any implicit conversion in line 4 and 5 ?

I'm using GCC compiler on 64-bit Mac.

Comment: They are all valid implicit conversion as far as I know. Line 1 will do assignment on bit level. There might be a flag on CPU level for line 3, but you are allowed to shift as much as you like. Line 4 and line 5 will take the data on the bit level and interpret it. Note that this is not answer, and facts might be incorrect.

Comment: BTW the correct format specifier for `size_t` in line 2 would be `%zu`, no need to cast the result of the `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 6):

1. You do not get an error because a negative integer constant is implicitly converted to an unsigned value, becoming a very large number (the MSB is set to one)
2. A value is implicitly converted to `int`<sup>1,2</sup>, shifted, and assigned back; you get all zeros when the number is converted back to `short`, but it is an undefined behavior<sup>3</sup>.
3. There are no *conversion* in lines 4 and 5 in the C sense; regular type promotions associated with passing arguments to variadic functions do apply. However, the `printf` re-interprets unsigned as singed on line 4: the format specifier is the only thing that tells `printf` of the type of the arguments passed to it.

---

<sup>1</sup>Promotions before shifting: [link](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.7).

<sup>2</sup>Integer promotions: [link](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.1.1).

<sup>3</sup> Shifting by 30 would be OK, because `2^30` is representable as an `int`.

Comment: Thanks! Now its making some sense.

Comment: It seems like `char`, `short` are promoted to `int` before shifting. Does the standard says anything about this?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight : Please explain one more thing

Say variable a and b are of type int and now I'm shifting 63 bits at the left 'coz long is of size 8 bytes or 64 bits. This time it throws an error instead of converting implicitly to long. Why ?

Comment: @RupsDell Shorts are promoted to int implicitly, but ints need to be converted to long explicitly. Shifting by a negative number or by more than the width of the argument is undefined behavior ([see the standard, part 6.5.7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.7)).

Comment: Even if it wasn't described in the standard, it wouldn't create an error anyway. At compile time there's no checks for constant numbers validity, so it wouldn't know "31" is too big. And a shift just puts zeros on the right, and removes the MSB... Overflows won't create an error or exception anyway.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer The standard requires that integer promotions are performed on both operands, so char and short will be converted to int implicitly ([link](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.7)).

Comment: Integer conversion seems to be discussed here: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.3.1.1 @dasblinkenlight: Can you edit your answer to include the references to the standard?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Line 3 is very probably undefined behaviour. Usually, 2^31 is not representable as an `int`, thus "If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned." applies then.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right, `2^31` is indeed not representable as an `int` (it fits in 32 bits, but it does not represent a positive number), so it's an undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, there's nothing that prohibits 48 or 64 bit `int`s, hence only "very probably".

Comment: @DanielFischer I think the OP mentioned something in his comments that made me believe that he's not on a platform with 64-bit `int`s. But 48 bits is a remote possibility, yes :)

Comment: For the OP, (s)he mentioned GCC, so you can safely bet on 32 bits. I was speaking generally.

Answer (score 2):

1) Negative integers are converted to unsigned by adding `UINT_MAX + 1` as per point 2 of [C99 6.3.1.3](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.1.3.html):

> ```
>  6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>  [...]
>  2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly
>  adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented
>  in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type.
> ```

2) Operands to the bit shift operators are implicitly converted to `int` as per [C99 6.5.7](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.7.html)

> ```
> 6.5.7 Bitwise Shift Operators
> 1 Each of the operands shall have integer type.
> 2 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.
> 3 The type of the result is that of the promoted left operand.
> ```

3) See dasblinkenlight's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Assigning**: Type which you give to your variable doesn't say what you can put there, but how the compiler should interpret it. In your case, -23 is 'translated' to 32 bits and then this value is put to unsigned int (which has also 32 bit) ... (bit lenght is architecture dependent)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

**Shifting**: When you shift, bits on one side 'goes away', on the other side bits (zeros) must be shifted in. You can shift variable how many times you want.

**Printfing**: Again, this is not about 'conversion' but about 'interpretation' of series of bits.